# Why does my Firebase Function keep returning false when the data should return true?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a Firebase Function to verify User's e-mail after signing up to my web app, however even after checking that a unique hash created on Sign Up matches a query in my function URL, the function is still returning false when it should return true i.e. user found

I am a relative newbie when it comes to async/await and promises, and I've tried using these in different places in the code to no effect.

```
exports.verifyMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    const hash = req.query.hash;

    const pendingUserKey = req.query.pendingUserKey;

    var pendingUser;

    admin
      .database()
      .ref('pending/' + pendingUserKey)
      .once('value', snapshot => {
        pendingUser = snapshot.val();
      })
      .then(function() {
        console.log(pendingUser);

        console.log(pendingUser.hash);

        console.log(hash);

        if (pendingUser.hash === hash) {
          return res.send('User hash matches');
        } else {
          return res.send('User not found');
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
});
```

The expected result is that the User has been found in the Database. Firebase console logs confirm that the pendingUser.hash and hash values are equal, yet the function still returns 'User not found' each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firebase console logs confirm that the pendingUser.hash and hash values are equal

Visually scanning log output isn't enough verification for 100% confidence that the values are truly equal.  Here are some cases where the values could be different with respect to JavaScript's `===` operator:

1. If one value is a string and another is an integer, they will not be equal, though logging output might appear that way.
2. If there is some trailing whitespace after either string, they will not be equal, though logging output might appear that way.

Since we here on Stack Overflow can't actually see the values, you'll need to dig in and figure out why those two values are not really equal according to the `===` operator.  So, make sure your database value isn't actually stored as a number, and also try checking the lengths of the strings to see if they really match.

Comment: Thank you Doug; this was indeed the case! Such a minor error had me looking in all sorts of wrong places. I went back and used parseInt() on both values and it worked! Thanks again, that was doing my head in